# Why does a media9 video move other things on my slide?

Tags: beamer, media9

In this MWE, there are points that appear on slide 1 and 3. On slide 2, when the video appears, the items that were generated on slide 1 move slightly. They then go back to there position when the video disappears.

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Why do the dot points move on slide 2?}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Point 1
                \item Point 2
                \item<3-> Point 3
            \end{itemize}

            \column{0.5\textwidth}
            \only<2>{
            \includemedia[
            width=0.6\linewidth,
            height=0.4\linewidth,
            activate=pageopen,
            addresource=PLT/sig0700compare_short.MP4,
            flashvars={source=PLT/sig0700compare_short.MP4}
            ]{}{VPlayer.swf}}
        \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the content of a slide is vertically aligned to be centred. If you add a large object, this needs room, so the text has to start further upwards in order to be vertically centred.

Some solutions:

- you could simply reserve the necessary room for the object on all slides by using for example `\visible` instead of `\only`.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Why do the dot points move on slide 2?}
      \begin{columns}
          \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Point 1
              \item Point 2
              \item<3-> Point 3
          \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \visible<2>{
              \rule{.6\linewidth}{.4\linewidth}
          }
        \end{column}
      \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- change the alignment of the slides to be top aligned either globally with `\documentclass[t]{beamer}` or for individual frame `\begin{frame}[t]`. In case of columns, they have to be separately top aligned with `\begin{columns}[T]`.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
      \frametitle{Why do the dot points move on slide 2?}
      \begin{columns}[T]
          \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Point 1
              \item Point 2
              \item<3-> Point 3
          \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \only<2>{
              \rule{.6\linewidth}{.4\linewidth}
          }
        \end{column}
      \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[replaced the video with a rectangle, as I cannot test without your file]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The [t] flag still has the same problem, it's just moved the items higher up the page - they still move though between slides 1 and 2. Visible works to keep them in the correct place, but I can see the video on slides 1 and 3 also.

Comment: @James Please see my edited answer.